# I don't see my login.html template

Tags: django, templates

Im a newbie in Django and I'm using Django-Cms. I'm trying to set a login page.

I have created this login.html template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

{% if form.errors %}
<p>Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.</p>
{% endif %}

<form method="post" action="{% url django.contrib.auth.views.login %}">
{% csrf_token %}
<table>
<tr>
    <td>{{ form.username.label_tag }}</td>
    <td>{{ form.username }}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>{{ form.password.label_tag }}</td>
    <td>{{ form.password }}</td>
</tr>
</table>

<input type="submit" value="login" />
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

My base.html is:

```
{% load cms_tags sekizai_tags %}
<html>
  <head>
      {% render_block "css" %}
  </head>
  <body>
      {% cms_toolbar %}
      {% placeholder base_content %}
      {% block base_content %}{% endblock %}
      {% render_block "js" %}
  </body>
</html>
```

My url is:

```
url(r'^accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
url(r'^accounts/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name': 'registration/login.html'}),
```

And when I go to /accounts/login I don't see anything. Just the django-cms toolbar. Why?

Thanks for reading

Comment: You should reverse the order in your `urls.py`, the `accounts/login/` pattern should come _before_ the `accounts/` pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably wanted to use `{% block base_content %}` instead `{% block content %}` in your login.html template as you have `{% block base_content %}` in your base.html template.